# Laravel: Is it good practice to use model relationships within a view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Laravel 5 view and I was wondering whether using model relationships inside of the views is actually a good thing to do, regarding perfomance.

Let's say a Car model has a one-to-one relationship with a Windshield.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Windshield Model</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <p class="form-control-static">{{$car->windshield->model}}</p>
        </div>                        
    </div>                        
</div>                                 
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Windshield Height</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <p class="form-control-static">{{$car->windshield->height}}</p>
        </div>                        
    </div>                        
</div>
```

My question here is, everytime I do a $car->windshield->someProperty Eloquent performs a query. Is this a good thing to do? I mean, what about performance?
If I want to show the n properties of the car's windshield, Eloquent will perform N queries, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not a good idea, because it's kind of anti MVC pattern. Also I'm not sure if caching will work fine in this case etc.

To solve N + 1 problem, you should use Eager loading:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

The code you are showing is exactly what is supposed to be.

If you were using it in the controller, the `N` queries would still be there.

As mentioned in the other answer, you must adhere to eager load to avoid `N + 1`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: but what if in the controller I do a single query using eager load. Let's say Car::with(['windshield', 'tires', ..., other properties]). Eloquent would translate this into a single query with joins. But when doing  $car->windshield N times whithin the view, it means the application will perform n times that query, or am I wrong?

Comment: After eager loading, `$car->windshield->height` will be resolved by Eloquent through arrays and object manipulation. The database won't be touched again. And remember, on top of eager loading you can also cache it.

Comment: let me get this right. The first time $car->windshield->height is called within the view, then the others $car->windshield->property won't go to the database and they'll work around cache? I'm sorry, I'm kind of a newbie on Larevel

Comment: No, those are separate statements. You can view the queries in action using laravel `debugbar`. That will solve most of your curiosities regarding this, as it did for me once.

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you